# Using rsync and which directories should I place in my exclude file when using rsync?

Tags: virtual-machines, rsync, mirroring, command, attributes

I would like to use a CentOS VM for a mirrored full backup of my CentOS mail server. Both are the same version and are up-to-date. I have found that without excluding certain directories the VM backup has kernel panic attacks and fails to load.

I use the following command to start the process:

> rsync -avz -Kl -p --numeric-ids --exclude-from=/rsync_exclude.txt -e 'ssh -2 -c blowfish-cbc' user@my.domain.com:/ /

**Question(s):**

1. Will there be any issues with the command being entered above?
2. Which directories should I include in my "rsync_exclude.txt" to prevent issues on the VM backup?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think this is the complete answer, but some are:

```
/sys
/proc
/tmp
/var/run
/var/lock
/dev
/mnt
# The following are stolen from Womble:
/var/cache
/var/tmp
/var/spool
```

Comment: I still get the kernel panic when excluding the mentioned folders

Answer (score 3):

Add `/var/cache`, `/var/tmp`, and `/var/spool` to Kyle's list.

Comment: You could have just put that in a comment on his post, I guess!

Comment: Or he could have taken all of mine, and then I get no points.  We like to share points :-)

Comment: I could have done a lot of things.