# rsync commands for thr following cases

Tags: linux, backup, rsync

I take a backup of my root directory (/) during shutdown to the attached storage and then rsync back from the attached storage to / during booting.

what's the rsync command I need to use during shutdown? Please tell me the list of directories to exclude

whats the rsync command I need to use during booting ? If there are any new files on the destination I dont want to overwrite them, when I do a rsync from source to destination

Answer (score 2):

I would create a file for my exclusions and use `--exclude-from=/rsync_exclude.txt`.  See [this post](https://serverfault.com/questions/85563/using-rsync-and-which-directories-should-i-place-in-my-exclude-file-when-using-rs/85565#85565) for the list of exclusions when backing up the root partition, as well as an example command.

That being said, I don't really understand what you are doing?  Why would you sync the files from the external storage at every boot?

Comment: I think its better if you put all files that you want to backup in to folder(s) and backup only that folder. Anyway, thanks for link of list of exclusions - i can use it for myself that one...

Answer (score 1):

The rsync man-page has all the details.

I usually do something like:

```
rsync -avh --exclude /tmp/ --exclude /var/tmp/ --exclude /$any_other_directory/ / /$backup_location/
```

To sync it back one would use:

```
rsync -avuh /$backup_location/ /
```

where the additional -u is "--update skip files that are newer on the receiver"